# Twitter Card Validator - Link to specific URL

Tags: url, twitter, twitter-card

I would like to give someone a link to check how a URL would look on a Twitter card. Currently, I send them to `https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator` and ask them to type in the URL. It would be more convenient to simply give a link that auto adds their URL.

Like this example:

> https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator?url=https://google.com

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter cards validator does not support having URLs passed in like that, so unfortunately this is still a two step process.